# Spark Shell -how to find whether ID has appeared maximum times in file

Tags: apache-spark

Find userID of user/s who has/have given maximum feedback to movies from textfile using Spark Shell

```
1:123
1:212
1:111
1:212
2:212
2:125
3:88
```

so I want to display use ID 1 who have given maximum feedback 
how can I find whether ID 1 has appeared maximum times in file?

```
scala>  val feedback = sc.textFile("/ratings.dat")     
scala>  val a = feedback.map(row => row.split("::")(0)).count     
a: Long = 1000209
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome.  Typically when asking questions it's a good idea to give a little more detail around your problem...  include type signatures...  what are the fields are in your data (I can infer it's ':' delimited and the first field is 'user id', but it's better if you're explicit).

Last thing...  where have you searched already...  what have you tried...  what problems are you running into?  Nobody here will teach you spark, but lots of people will help you through obstacles.

I'd go about it w something like this, if the assumptions I've made are correct...  also note, I use RDDs and not dataframes, so if you want a specific format, again...  best to specify in the question.

```
val ids_w_counts: RDD[(String, Int)] = {
  feedback
    .rdd                                    // convert to RDD
    .map(row => (row.split(":").head, 1))   // extract to (user_id, 1)
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)                     // now you have (user_id, total entries)
  }

// max number of entries by one user_id
val max_id_cnt: Int = ids_w_cnts.map(_._2).max

// filter all users to just those with max entries
val top_users = ids_w_counts.filter(_._2 == max_id_cnt).collect

// print in shell; again specify format if you need it differently
top_users.foreach(println)
```

Comment: thank you @kmh for suggestions! I have tried your solution but I am getting 2 errors      <console>:26: error: not found: type RDD
       val ids_w_counts: RDD[(String, Int)] = {
                                     ^
<console>:27: error: value rdd is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
         feedback.rdd.map(row => (row.split("::").head, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
                         ^

Comment: first error is probably that you didn't import...  `import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`; second error could be that you read data in as an `RDD[Row]`, so the attempted conversion to an RDD (`.rdd` applied to feedback) was unnecessary.  try adding the import at the top, and if you still get the second error, try removing the `.rdd` line.